# apiary commend line tools responds with 503

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

I am using command line apiary tool (offline), to generate the documentation in HTML format. Occasionally I have seen this error "Apiary service responded with an error: 503 Service Unavailable". My question are

1. what does this error mean.
2. Does this offline tool contacts some external apiary service  which were not reachable at that point of time when error was received.

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to the [Apiary CLI](https://github.com/apiaryio/apiary-client), it may need to connect to the Apiary server for some operations.

It would be great if you could provide other informations, such as

1. Confirm we're talking about Apiary CLI
2. Context and command executed
3. Did you set your `APIARY_API_KEY`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is the information you asked for.
1. Yes, I am referring to the Apiary CLI. 
2. Command executed is "apiary preview --path=api.apib --output api.html". 
3. No, I didn't set the APIARY_API_KEY.

Comment: Hey,
at first, you should definitely have a look to the [documentation](http://client.apiary.io)

Furthermore, the tool has been updated recently, ensure to have got latest version.

About your problem, apiary client uses online apiary services to render your documentation, so it may happen to receive that error if server is offline.

If you're looking for a complete offline renderer, you should have a loot at [aglio](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio)

Comment: Thanks Vincenzo for the response. I followed the documentation earlier (about 2-3 months ago) when I installed the apiary CLI but didn't follow up the updates later. As per the documentation "If you want to use this tool only to preview locally, you can skip these steps", so I didn't set the APIARY_API_KEY. Let me refer to aglio for offline renderer as that seems to be  more suitable for my needs.